# Cut a magnet into smaller pieces

Tags: magnetism

I salvaged this 10 lb magnet from a 1000 watt speaker.

I trying to make smaller magnets from it.

Wikihow says to either chip it with a hammer or saw it with a hacksaw.

I am looking for ideas on accomplishing that.

[image]

Comment: It might just be cheaper and more effective to buy magnets that are better sized to your requirements, or maybe see if anyone you know has a stack of old hard disks lying around that you can raid for parts; the magnets in a hard disk are a much more manageable size than this one and won't be contaminated with large amounts of magnetic dust like this one will be when you're done cutting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are typically "ferrites". Not metals but intermetallics. So they are not malleable /deformable like metal. Think of it as having physical properties like a ceramic- hard, brittle. It may be cuttable with an abrasive wheel but you may need a diamond wheel as would be used for ceramics,

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to cut a speaker magnet with a hacksaw because the magnet material is harder than the hacksaw teeth.

You can *break* a magnet into smaller pieces by *scribing* the break lines onto the magnet surface with a single point diamond scribe and then flipping the magnet over and striking the backside of the magnet surface with a hammer and chisel, where the chisel edge is aligned with the direction of the scribe line on the opposite side.

But the best way to accurately separate a magnet into smaller pieces is with a diamond-wheel grinder.

Note that the most common magnet material used in big and cheap loudspeakers is *barium ferrite*. This is what your magnet is made of, which is not the strongest magnetic material available. Small *rare earth* magnets are on a per pound basis far stronger and can be bought cheaply in a variety of shapes.

Comment: Diamond wheel grinder wheel grinder is way to expensive. But i do appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I bought a 230mm diamond angle-grinder disk for £5 from a discount retailer a couple of years ago. Amazon have a pack of 6 of the small disks for £13.

Comment: I saw one for $20. @Lefty

Comment: Of course, you can pay £20 if you want, but Amazon have these 6 small ones for £12.99 and a 230mm one for £10.76. I realise that I was lucky to get mine for £5, but you don't need to pay £20. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tooltime%C3%82%C2%AE-115mm-Grinder-Diamond-Cutting/dp/B01BJQUU3A/ref=sr_1_7?crid=3FWEP70TFKFO1&dchild=1&keywords=diamond+cutting+disc&qid=1595184512&sprefix=diamond+cu%2Caps%2C148&sr=8-7

Comment: I do not live in the U.K. but the U.S. It's says it can not be shipped to my location.@Lefty